# Jira is not recognising my upload from CSV

Tags: excel, csv, jira

I'm creating a CSV template for some analysts, they would need to fill it and I then do a bulk upload to Jira.

I want to upload them as defects. The issue I'm facing is:

I have a label when filling out a defect and I want to select one of the options, so for example I have a label called 'Label A' and it has 3 options in a list.

In the excel file I put the top row as 'Label A' and under it for one of the entries I put the full name of one of the options (Displayed on JIRA) for example 'Option A'. But I write this in the excel file as : Option A

But after uploading it does not recognise this and returns a validation error.

This is the same for a tick box label, for e.g. 'Label B'

However any text that I put up, (Something that requires free text and is not a multiple option) like for example 'Summary', I would put any random text e.g. 'abcd', and this will validate fine.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong with the way I'm formatting my CSV for when I upload answers to multiple choice parts of a defect?

Comment: Is the 'Label A' field a custom field of type select list (single choice)?

Comment: Should this question be on Project Management? http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jira

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you can create a sample issue (like you need to be upload) in jira then you can export(Export all fields) that created issue and analyse the output excel file. then you can understand the input format that jira required form your CSV file.

**UPDATED**

the other thing you can do is read the JIRA log file it will tell you the actual error occurred  some times.

are you export your created issue with this  option?..see screenshot below..

[image]

Comment: I have tried looking into this, you can export the search result but not the content of the individual issue.. So I can't see the formatting

Comment: then you can use JQL to filter your newly created issue then export it by using all fields.

Comment: the actual format of the excel just shows the issue number and a hyperlink of the issue tracking back to the KANBAN board and not the actual fields

Comment: can you tell me how did you export the issue you created?.

Answer (score 3):

The approach will depend on the field types you are using.

For example, if you were loading a simple text field then the text in the CSV file will just be inserted in to the text field.

If, however, you are populating a custom field that is represented by a radio button or a drop-down listbox then you will need to use the field mapping option that is offered during the CSV import.

Say you had a radio button that said either 'true' or 'false'. You would tick the mapping option for this field during the CSV import and configure it to map true -> true and false -> false. You can also do this mapping in the CSV file itself.

You can see more details on this link:

[Atlassian - Importing Data from CSV](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Importing+Data+from+CSV)

Comment: Hi, I could do the mapping option during the import maybe but the problem is at this point I upload 300+ on to JIRA.... I have already looked at the documentation (link provided) before asking a question here on Stack Overflow like I always do, but I couldn't find what I'm after from the Atlassian docs, however I was scanning through instead of reading line by line... I'll look more closely.

Comment: You should only need to do the mapping option once during the import. JIRA recognises all the values you are trying to insert in to a field and asks you to map them to a field value.

Answer (score -1):

The approach you can follow is as below:

1. Count the number of labels in the Issue you are trying to import.
2. Every label should go into its own separate column for it to be imported properly. 
   Eg:- If there are 5 labels for an issue, create 5 Labels_CSV(or what suits you) column in the CSV header row and put the 5 labels in the data row.
3. Once the CSV is created, try to upload it with your existing config file which has mapping for Labels_CSV --> Labels.
4. Voila, the multiple labels will be imported properly.

Let me know if you have any queries.